# Reading an image in flask

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do a flak server to process images, send by CURL and I am finding some problems when trying to read the image in a PIL.

The code is very simple:

At the server side, the "calibrate" route is coded as:

@app.route('/calibrate', methods=['POST'])
def calibrate():

```
if flask.request.files.get("image"):
    
    # read the image in PIL format
    image_b = flask.request.files["image"].read()
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_b))
    #convert to Numpy
    image_np = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)

    # Process the image
    # ....

    image_buf = Image.fromarray(image_np)

return flask.send_file(image_buf, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

And I send a CURL request as:

!curl http://localhost:5000/calibrate -X POST -F 'image=@image_in.jpg' -o 'result.jpg'

I get this error:

127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2023 17:44:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path to python/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 576, in **next**
data = self.file.read(self.buffer_size)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'

If I try to read the image directly with:

image = Image.open(request.files['file'].stream)

I get the same error..

I would appreciate very much any help !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple of working code for that purpose I used in a previous project. feel free to use it :

```py
@bp.route('/photography', methods=['POST'])
def create_photography():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'no file', 400
    file = request.files['file']
    if not re.search(r'\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$', file.filename):
        return 'wrong file format, only one accepted are jpg, jpeg, png', 400
    try:
        data = file.read()
        #here you can do anything with your file as with any opened python file
        return "okay", 200
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error("canot read file, error = " +str(e))
        return 'bad request', 410
```

For some cybersecurity purpose it could be useful to add a safe file verification before proceed the content.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
image_buf = Image.fromarray(image_np)
```

because that makes a Python object of class `PIL.Image` and the browser is expecting a JPEG-encoded image. So you need:

```
# Create a PIL image from the Numpy array
pi = Image.fromarray(image_np)

# Create "in-memory" space to write a JPEG into
from io import BytesIO
buffer = BytesIO()

# Save PIL Image in buffer in JPEG format
pi.save(buffer,format='jpg')
JPG = buffer.getvalue()

return flask.send_file(JPG, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```